# Device Agent doesn't see Timex Ironman Global Trainer

Tags: 14.04, usb, wine

I am a new user of Ubuntu 14.04.

The device agent software is working fine under Wine but it does not see my Timex Ironman Global Trainer watch when I connect it via USB.

I've seen that other people report the same issue on internet but could not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the Timex Ironman Global Trainer to work using a Windows virtual machine under Ubuntu Linux. You do need a copy of Windows (XP in my case), or something like TinyXP  (since it's just a step in the process I'll leave the ethical concerns to the user). I'll outline the process just to point anyone interested in the right direction.

-Install VirtualBox, as well as VirtualBox Guest Additions (needed for USB support), and add your user name to the vboxusers group.

-Download the latest Timex Device Agent from Timex and [STM32 Virtual Com Port Driver] from http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257938

-Create a Windows machine with a Shared Folder access to where you downloaded the Timex and STM software.

-Under the Windows machine install the Timex and STM driver (choose 32 bit or 64 bit based on your copy of Windows). Close the Windows machine down.

-Plug in your Timex to a USB port. Under VirtualBox Manager ->Settings -> USB enable both check boxes for the USB controller. Press the second button on the right (plus sign icon). One of the choices should be "STMElectronics STM32 Virtual COM Port". Select this one. You are adding a USB filter to allow the watch to tunnel to the virtual copy of Windows.

-Start the Windows machine, then put the watch into PC Sync (pressing the Mode button on the watch). If you start the Device Agent in Windows (skip the Training Peaks login/account creation unless it applies to you) you should be able to download workouts, configure the watch, and update the firmware as usual. You can save the downloaded files into a Shared Folder to work with them under Ubuntu or upload them to Training Peaks.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I think this may be the only solution although I will need a valid Windows key to do it. Since I am not a fan of illegal ｗａｙs， this means I wｏｕld have to buy Windows :/